# CCA security of this scheme

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, distinguisher

Let $k$ be uniformly sampled from $\{0,1\}^\lambda$, $F$ be a secure PRP with block length $\lambda$ and let $Enc(k, m)$ be such that it returns $c = (F(k,r), r \oplus F(k,m))$ with $r$ uniformly sampled from $\{0,1\}^\lambda$. How to prove that this scheme is not CCA secure? In particular, how can an attack be thought of?

Comment: You mean scheme.

Comment: Thanks. I think that also for these reasons there is an 'edit' button clickable by everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

I won't give the answer; here are some hints:

- Suppose we have a valid cipher text $(A, B) = F(k, r), r \oplus F(k, m)$.  What happens if we modify the ciphertext to be $(A, B \oplus C)$ and get that decrypted?
- How can we use this?  What can we do if we have two ciphertexts that encrypt the same message $m$?

Comment: Thinking about the decryption algorithm, can be $F^{-1}(k, F^{-1}(k,A) \oplus B)$, but now I can't see which $C$ can be useful in this scenario. I'll think about it